# Need to create a Datatable in a simple way.

Tags: datatable

Need a help in Datatable development. I faced some difficulties creating it by myself. Please, answer, how to create a Datatable? Desirably without libraries.

Comment: Provide information on how and what you have achieved so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution which I have applied in my practice. The code is large enough, so I will present you a piece of code. Have a look. There are templete functions
1)for example, for displaying all users:

```
function userTemplate(user) {
return '<div class="content-column-data">'+
'<img class="customer-image" src="../../../assets/images/customer/'+ user.img +'">'+
'<div class="customer-name">'+ user.name +'</div>'+
'</div>');
}
```

2)for displaying all table cells:

```
function mainBlockAdd(adress, itemInfo){
   $(adress).append(
       '<div class="content-column-data">'+
       itemInfo +
       '</div>'
   );
}
```

Them we should transfer all received data:

```
function loadTable(responseNew){
   $('.noRes').hide();
   left_people_block_show(responseNew);
   store_show(responseNew);
   customer_details_show(responseNew);
   reservations_show(responseNew);
   activity_show(responseNew);
   $('#static-columns').show();
   $('#sortable-overlay').show();
   showTopBtn();
   hideBlocks();
}
```

If my code seems helpful to you, use its full version from this article:
http://computoolsglobal.com/blog/how-to-create-a-datatable-manually-without-the-use-of-libraries/

Comment: Thank you! It helped me.